# How get lastModified Property of file add in head?

Tags: javascript, jquery, last-modified

I have a JS file add in `head` and would to get the `lastModified` property. I tried this but doesn't work:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://www.website.fake/code/quakes48h.js" type="text/javascript" id="utlime48ore"></script>
</head>
```

```js
var last_mod48 = document.getElementById("ultime48ore").src.lastModified;
alert(last_mod48);
```

This returns error `is null`. I hope you can help me.

Comment: You cannot get the last modified date of a file like this.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is there other way ?

Comment: If you're attempting to get the date the file was last saved on the server, then no. You cannot get that information from a public request

Comment: how can i understand if this file is update ? what do you suggest ?

Comment: Possibly make an AJAX request to it and hope their server is confgured to include a `Last-Modified` header. If it doesn't, and its unlikely that it will, then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @Borja This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140350). *Why* do you need to know when the file was last modified? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation of the `lastModified` property at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/lastModified) and [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_lastmodified.asp).

From W3Schools :

> The lastModified property returns the date and time the current
>   document was last modified.

From MDN :

> Returns a string containing the date and time on which the current
>   document was last modified.

What you are attempting to achieve with this property is not what it is meant for. Returning `null` is normal because you are trying to check the lastModified of a non HTML DOM `document` object which won't have it set.

If the intent is to get the last modification date of a file, it is best done on the server side in my opinion.

-- EDIT based on OPs mention of PHP --

If you are using PHP and wish to get the last modification time of a file local to the server, you could use the php `filemtime($filename)` Filesystem function. Documentation may be found [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)

Example out of the documentation cited above :

```
<?php
// outputs e.g.  somefile.txt was last modified: December 29 2002 22:16:23.

$filename = 'somefile.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}
?>
```

Comment: i have a php file that every 2 minute create these js file and delete previous version. I use this js file on browser and i want to pars this js file only if is update version. But i have to understand if is really update... but if i can't use lastModified do you know is there other way ?

Comment: by server side ? how ? wtih php ? can you suggest me something please

Comment: `file_exists` won't work here as the file is remote, not local to the server

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see ... Question to OP : is the File located remotely or it is always updated on the server itself ?

Comment: Updated the answer !.